# C# & SQL Unable to pull Data from Permissions Table

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio

I have a permissions database that I created which has 10 data points in it. I can insert data into this table through the program, but when I try to pull the data it's been giving me a lot of headaches. I've attempted to use a Using loop and it errors out every time, so I'm trying to just go super basic, and pull the data line by line but it's not working at all. My goal is to pull all the data into a List Variable so that I can call each individual permission later. What is stored in each permission is simply the Text True or False, with the exception of the first one Emp_ID being an Int.

Con is my connection script, and it's working perfectly, as it works everywhere else within the program.

Settings.Emp_ID is the Emp_ID of the user that's currently logged in. This means that we can skip the Emp_ID from the permissions when pulling the data, but I've attempted to do an EXCLUDE or SKIP but it's failed every time as well.

SQL Format, Emp_ID = INT, all others = Text

As for Error:

> System.NullReference Exception 'Object Reference Not set to an instance of an object.

```
namespace TMS
{
    public partial class Login_Form : Form
    {
        string[] Data;
        void verify()
        {
            SqlDataReader rdr = null;
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Permissions WHERE Emp_ID = '"
                + Settings.Emp_ID + "'", Con);
            try
            {
                Con.Open();

                rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                while (rdr.Read())
                {
                    int Emp_ID = (int)rdr["Emp_ID"];
                    Data[0] = (string)rdr["Check_Out"];
                    Data[1] = (string)rdr["Check_In"];
                    Data[2] = (string)rdr["Self_His_Tool"];
                    Data[3] = (string)rdr["Self_His_User"];
                    Data[4] = (string)rdr["Tool_His"];
                    Data[5] = (string)rdr["User_His"];
                    Data[6] = (string)rdr["Add_Users"];
                    Data[7] = (string)rdr["Add_Tools"];
                    Data[8] = (string)rdr["Remove_Users"];
                    Data[9] = (string)rdr["Remove_Tools"];
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                if (rdr != null)
                {
                    rdr.Close();
                }
                if (Con != null)
                    Con.Close();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Post code as formatted text rather than an image. Include the error message or symptoms instead of saying "it's not working at all".

Comment: Yikes, this looks scary-vulnerable to sql injection issues.

Comment: Its for a school project, going nowhere.

Comment: SQL injection is one of those things you should not mess around with... not even for school, learning, or proof of concept projects.

Answer (score 1):

The `Data` array is still `null`, because this line does not actually create an array object:

```
string[] Data;
```

All it does is create a variable that might someday refer to an array object.

Later, when you have this and lines like it:

```
Data[0] = (string)rdr["Check_Out"];
```

You end up with the NullReferenceException. `Data` is still null, and so trying to access `Data[0]` is not allowed.

We want something more like this:

```
public class Permissions
{
    //probably these should be "bool", but I adapted the types from the old code
    public string Check_Out {get;set;}
    public string Check_In {get;set;}
    public string Self_His_Tool {get;set;}
    public string Self_His_User {get;set;}
    public string Tool_His {get;set;}
    public string User_His {get;set;}
    public string Add_Users {get;set;}
    public string Add_Tools {get;set;}
    public string Remove_Users {get;set;}
    public string Remove_Tools {get;set;}
}

// ...

Permissions Data;

Permissions verify()
{
    string SQL = "SELECT * FROM Permissions WHERE Emp_ID = @Emp_ID";

    // Do NOT re-use the some connection object throughout an app or class!
    // Only re-use the connection string.
    // using directive will ensure connection is closed, so no need for finally block
    using var con = new SqlConnection("connection string here");
    using var cmd = new SqlCommand(SQL, con);

    // Do NOT use string concatation to substitute data into a query!
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Emp_ID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Settings.Emp_ID;

    // don't need a "try" if there's no catch or finally

    con.Open();
    rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    Permissions result = null;
    if (rdr.Read()) //Don't need "while" if we only expect one record
    {
        result = new Permissions();
        int Emp_ID = Settings.Emp_ID;
        result.Check_out =(string)rdr["Check_Out"];
        result.Check_In = (string)rdr["Check_In"];
        result.Self_His_Tool = (string)rdr["Self_His_Tool"];
        result.Self_His_User = (string)rdr["Self_His_User"];
        result.Tool_His = (string)rdr["Tool_His"];
        result.User_His = (string)rdr["User_His"];
        result.Add_Users = (string)rdr["Add_Users"];
        result.Add_Tools = (string)rdr["Add_Tools"];
        result.Remove_Users = (string)rdr["Remove_Users"];
        result.Remove_Tools = (string)rdr["Remove_Tools"];
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: So in order to prevent SQL injection, what would I need to do differently? Also I noticed in Visual Studio there’s no way for it to save a Bool in the built in database manager, what would be the best way, to convert the string to Bool or to somehow save it as a bool within the Database?

Comment: I'm getting an error Use of Unassigned Local Variable 'result'

I'm getting this in the return result; line

Comment: The answer demonstrates how to avoid injection. I also fixed the unassigned variable error.